# How do I access a relational SQL database from C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, rdbms

First of all, I can do this in Java, using JDBC. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of JDBC for C#. It needs to access all types of databases. My searches have not revealed anything useful to me.
EDIT: For now, I'm going to try ADO.NET

Comment: @marc_s All types of SQL servers.

Comment: Did somebody just downvote my question?

Comment: downvotes are likely because of the broadness of the subject.

Comment: Well, what I'm looking for is broad-ish. But in a way, I'm being specific by asking for an equivalent to JDBC. I got my answer, and it just seems wrong to downvote for being broad.

Comment: In addition to the downvotes, this is definitely something you should have been able to google easily. For example I just now googled 'equivalent of jdbc for c charp' and recieved plenty of answers to this question. Questions that can be answered by the first result of a google search do not belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: @kingfrito_5005 When I googled it, I (at the time) didn't see anything that looked like it would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very broad question but you'll probably want [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx), that should get you started.

> ADO.NET provides consistent access to data sources such as SQL Server and XML, and to data sources exposed through OLE DB and ODBC. Data-sharing consumer applications can use ADO.NET to connect to these data sources and retrieve, handle, and update the data that they contain.

Comment: Does this support most types of SQL?

Comment: @FireFaced Yes. Each vendor can provide their own 'adapter', just like JDBC. There are the customary differences and many vendors provided specialized types.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

ADO.Net is the .Net native equivalent for handling database access.
[MSDN link to ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)